# How to install Kivy on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python, kivy

How can I build and install [kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) from source ?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository with:

```
git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy
cd kivy
```

It could be that you still need some extra packages. To install them, do:

```
sudo apt-get install cython
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-ttf-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-image-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-mixer-dev
```

For a standard build use:

```
make
```

Or for a build with MesaGL use:

```
make mesabuild
```

And install with:

```
sudo make install
```

But I suggest using `checkinstall`:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall python setup.py install
```

Comment: ok, where os the installation ?

Comment: @begueradj Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)